# Creating a temporary Observable inside a method

Tags: rx-java, reactive

Code:

```
static void readCharacteristic( RxBleDevice device, UUID characteristic, Action1<byte[]> callback ) {
    Observable<RxBleConnection> deviceConnObservable = getSharedConnectionObservable( device );
    deviceConnObservable
        .subscribe(
                callback, 
                throwable -> Log.d( TAG, "Error" ),
                () -> {  } // completed the read
        );
}
```

I presume that when the method is exited, `deviceConnObservable` is destroyed. But what about the handlers in the `Subscriber`? Are they gone, too, or do they live on and get called--perhaps the `onError()` handler when the `Observable` is destroyed?

Assuming they don't, is there ever a case where it's OK to create an `Observable` in a method? Seems like it should be OK if you wait for its `onCompleted()` notification, no?

Comment: Observables that have been subscribed to are either executed synchronously on the current thread (so will finish before your method does) or are executed using a scheduler in which case the scheduler will hold a reference to the observable chain, including the delegates, until the observable completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `getSharedConnectionObservable` is running in the current thread, the subscription completed before the method exited.

If your `getSharedConnectionObservable` is asynchronous, there exisits a reference chain to your `Observable`.

`Worker(Thread)` -> `Task(Action0)` -> {`DownStream(Subscriber)` & `UpStream(Observable)`(`OperatorSubscribeOn`)}

Your `Observable` will be completed, and you can try it yourself.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand, the Scheduler for an async Observable holds a reference so that even when the method finishes, the Observable lives on. When the Scheduler is done with it (presumably by unsubscribe() or onComplete()), it's deallocated and can be GC'd. Correct?

Comment: @RobertLewis Yes